# How can I increase the overall gain on this circuit?

Tags: transistors, distortion

This is a circuit from Nicholus Boscorelli's Stompbox Cookbook, page 194. The circuit introduces crossover distortion. i built it and it works fine. However it won't go past unity gain which wouldn't be a problem but as the potentiometer is turned to increase the distortion, the volume decreases. What can I change in the circuit to increase the gain?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it doesn't look to me like you can adjust any component value to tune the voltage gain much in this circuit. You can add an amplification stage though ...

Comment: Thanks. I was building a jfet boost while trying to figure out how to upload the picture of the schematic. Gave up on android, used my pc:)